# multi subscriber of a spring integration ExecutorChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In my application I configure some channels as follows:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel eventFilterChannel() {
    return new ExecutorChannel(asyncConfiguration.getAsyncExecutor());
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel processEventChannel() {
    return new ExecutorChannel(asyncConfiguration.getAsyncExecutor());
}
```

I am using `ExecutorChannel` and using my custom `Executor` as follows:

```
@Configuration  
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyAppThread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I have the following `MessageEndpoint` which is a subscriber to the `eventFilterChannel` channel:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MyEventFilter {

    @Filter(inputChannel = "eventFilterChannel", outputChannel = "processEventChannel")
    public boolean filterEvents(final MyEvent myEvent) {

            //filter logic

    }

}
```

Ideally, I would expect my event filter message endpoint to be multi-threaded as I am using `ExecutorChannel`. I would like to understand if this is the correct implementation of multithreaded endpoint?

However, I am doubtful because I could see the following in my logs:

```
Channel 'application.eventFilterChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

Is my implementation correct or is there a standard I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a bit of misleading. Your `eventFilterChannel` really has only one subscriber - your `@Filter`. But it is indeed multi-threaded. The same stateless component is used in several threads.

The `ExecutorChannel` queues incoming tasks and they are performed on the threads in the pool - in parallel. In our case the story is about messages delivery. Not sure if code can help you but it looks like:

```
public final boolean dispatch(final Message<?> message) {
    if (this.executor != null) {
        Runnable task = createMessageHandlingTask(message);
        this.executor.execute(task);
        return true;
    }
    return this.doDispatch(message);
}
```

Where that `Runnable` is like this:

```
public void run() {
    doDispatch(message);
}
...

handler.handleMessage(message);
```

This `handler` is exactly a subscriber for that `@Filter`.
So, the same method is called from different threads. Since this is passive and stateless component it is just safe to keep it only once and reuse from different threads.

On the other hand, out of topic: if you add more subscribers to this channel, they are not going to be called in parallel anyway: By default it is round-robin strategy: the handler for next message is selected according the index. 
If one handler fails to process message, we try the next and so on. You can inject any other custom implementation though. Or even reset it to `null` to always start from the first one.